# How to change the parameter type in crystal report of the existing report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report with 2 subreports. The type of the one of the field got changed in the database from number to string. The main report has no parameters but the subreport has this parameter. Now when I try to run the report I get the error in the record selection formula. A string is expected here. My question is How do I make the type change for that field so that I can run my report. ?

Comment: Could you try posting some of your code, please?  Also, the actual text of the error might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remap the bindings of the report with the changed datatype in the dataset

Answer (score 1):

Easy to do.  And FUN, too!

Assuming you can change the link to the subreport, you can:

1)  create a formula to manipulate that field in the main report, explicitly converting it into the format you neend.  Then, 
2)  use THAT formula as the link to the subreport

Should work a charm, "Bob's yer oncle", and all that.

Comment: I modified the field to change it from Number to string        IsNull ({Table1.ct_nbr}) or cstr({Table1.ct_nbr})="0". How do I use this formula to link to the subreport

Comment: Replace what the subreport uses as its parameter with the forumla.  You can usually do this by rt-click on the subreport and selecting Change Links

Comment: I went to the subreport and changed the parameter type to string.But after I do that the link blanks out, if I try to modify the link.The available field keeps on clearing, my question is I cannot type while creating link, I only get to select

Comment: Sanika, I don't think you should change the parameter type in the subreport (based on my understanding of your description).  Leave that as number, but create your formula in the main report that converts the (now) string type back into a number type.  In the Change Links context menu of the MAIN report, use the new formula in place of the current field, and link that to the CURRENT field/param shown for the subreport.

Comment: But I don't want to convert this field because originally it was a numeric field and now it's an alplhanumeric field

Comment: Sanika, The field in the (main) report will stay the same.  The formula is only used so that you have a numeric value to use as a link for the subreport.  If you NEED a numberic field for the (now useless) link to the subreport, and the NEWLY converted alphanumeric field contains that (now TEXT) number, the only way you're going to get it is by a conversion for the subreport.  Well, I can think of other ways, but it's too messy, and we don't have a flux capacitor.  Just try it.  You don't have to use the formula for anything else -- just an updated link param.  Pip-pip, cheerio.